# Is there a zoom function in safari

Tags: macos

I'm a newbie to Mac (coming from Microsoft world). I wan't to zoom in / out a webpage in Safari, but cannot find a way to do it (in Windows I would just hit ctrl + mouse wheel), but that doesn't seem to work. I don't wan't to zoom the whole desktop, just the webpage to get the fonts etc. little bit bigger. Is there some key-combination i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command and + at the same time. Command and - will zoom out.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Macbook, there are some trackpad motions you can use. Otherwise, you can also use control+scroll up/down to zoom in/out (scrolling by either using two fingers on the trackpad or using a scroll button on your mouse (if you're using a Mighty Mouse then there's a motion you can use for scrolling)).

Comment: I'm on MacMini, and I have Microsoft keyboard + Logitech mouse (so i'm a low-budget lamer :)

Comment: So as I said, ctrl+scroll will give you a true zoom function. There's a section in the system preferences to control where the zoom focus goes - for instance, you can have it set to follow the mouse, or not.

Comment: ctrl + scroll just scrolls the webpage up and down

Comment: It's possible it's currently disabled. Go to your system preferences and search for 'zoom'.

Comment: the command + mouse wheel just zooms the whole desktop.. command + (+) or (-) works though.. I just wanted to use mouse for the zoom but maybe i have to get used to using key combinations

Comment: As I said, the mouse wheel is a true zoom. The +/- will just increase the font size and such. Personally I use the true zoom because oftentimes the things I'm wanting to make larger aren't affected by the +/- key commands. Also, depending on which logitech mouse you have, and depending on how much support Logitech has given it for Mac, you may be able to assign whichever zoom function you like to any extra mouse buttons.